# scipy.optimize.minimize throwing error: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scipy-optimize

I want to minimize a function with certain constrainsts. In the below code A= 4 by 4 matrix, v= 4 by 1 vector and alpha is a random scalar value. In order to avoid the error " only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars", I have done vectorization of the constraint and the objective function. However, still no luck and the same error is appearing.

```
import random
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from numpy.linalg import norm

def calculateV(params):
    return norm(params)

#Declaring the equation here
def objective(x):
    alpha = x[0]
    v=x[1:len(x)]
    vnorm=calculateV(v)
    return alpha+(vnorm/2)

#Need to vectorize the objective function to avoid only size 1 arrays can be converted 
#to Python scalars
f=np.vectorize(objective)

#Declaring the constraint here
def constraint(x):
   alpha=x[0]
   v=x[1:len(x)]
   vnorm=calculateV(v)
   return A*v-alpha
c=np.vectorize(constraint)   

#starting values
startalpha=random.random();
shape=(4,1)
startv=np.random.uniform(0,1,shape)
val_start=[startalpha,startv] 

cons={'type':'ineq','fun':c}

result=minimize(f,val_start,constraints=cons,options={"disp":True})   

if result.success:
  print("Success")
else:
  print("Sorry could not compute a minimum")
```

The traceback error message is :-

```
------Start--------
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-4-a3839c47e06a>", line 46, in <module>
    result=minimize(objective,val_start,constraints=cons,options={"disp":True})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 618, in minimize
    constraints, callback=callback, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/slsqp.py", line 308, in _minimize_slsqp
    x = asfarray(x0).flatten()
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in asfarray
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 114, in asfarray
    return asarray(a, dtype=dtype)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

------End--------
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py:479: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  x0 = np.asarray(x0)
```

Comment: Before throwing random `vectorize` at your problem, have you determined which parameter or value has to be a scalar (or single element array)?  Take out the `vectorize` and show the **full error message with traceback**.  We need a **close** reason specifically for this!

Comment: Traceback has been given above!

Answer (score 0):

Without a proper error message I'm guessing, but here's a bit of code that looks suspicious.

```
In [236]: startalpha=random.random();
     ...: shape=(4,1)
     ...: startv=np.random.uniform(0,1,shape)
     ...: val_start=[startalpha,startv]
     ...: 
In [237]: val_start
Out[237]: 
[0.272350113689266,
 array([[0.12736234],
        [0.69036025],
        [0.24118139],
        [0.68033726]])]
```

Review the `minimize` docs, and tell me if that is a legitimate parameter.

Comment: Is there any other way to send these two parameters to the scipy.minimize? startv is actually a vector of n dimension!

Comment: Your `val_start` is a 2 element list, not a (n,) shape array (which is what `minimize` expects).  Try `np.asarray(val_start, dtype=float)` yourself .  The traceback confirms my guess.  It is trying to make a flat array from `x0`.